# Adicionar mascara a partir de um select

Tags: jquery, html-select

Bom dia, estou tentando adicionar uma mascara para cpf a partir de um select, mas não estou conseguindo.

HTML

```
<select class="form-control" id="select" style="width:100px;" title="Escolha..." name="select"> 
    <option>Escolha...</option>             
    <option value="user_nome">Nome</option>
    <option value="user_cpf">CPF</option>
    <option value="user_email">Email</option>
    <option value="user_loja">Loja</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="busca" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite sua busca" name="busca" style="width:250px;">
```

jQuery:

```
var $select = $('#select option:selected').val();
if( $select == "CPF") {
    var $busca = $('#busca');
    $busca.mask('999.999.999-99');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complementando a resposta da @Jessika, segue um alternativa utilizando a função `change()` do próprio jquery.

*Nota que é necessário utilizar o [mask plugin jquery](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js)
*O método `unmask()` remove a máscara do campo, caso não seja CPF.

```js
$("#select").change(function() {
  addMaskToInput();
});

function addMaskToInput() {
  var $select = $('#select option:selected').val();
  var $busca = $('#busca');
  if ($select == "user_cpf") {
    $busca.mask('999.999.999-99');
  } else {
    $busca.unmask();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js">
</script>
<select class="form-control" id="select" style="width:100px;" title="Escolha..." name="select"> 
    <option>Escolha...</option>             
    <option value="user_nome">Nome</option>
    <option value="user_cpf">CPF</option>
    <option value="user_email">Email</option>
    <option value="user_loja">Loja</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="busca" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite sua busca" name="busca" style="width:250px;">
```

Comment: Obrigado cara, dessa forma funcionou certinho.

Answer (score 0):

Note que o valor da opção CPF não é "CPF".

```
<option value="user_cpf">CPF</option>
```

Ênfas em:

```
value="user_cpf"
```

Você precisa alterar a sua comparação de valores para:

```
if( $select == "user_cpf") {
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom vc precisa colocar um evento no select para chamar sua função quando o `select` é alterado. Outra coisa que vc está fazendo errado é na comparação do `if`, pois vc tem que comparar com o `value` do `option` ("user_cpf") e não com o "CPF";

```js
document.getElementById("select").addEventListener("change", myFunction);
function myFunction(){
 var $select = $('#select option:selected').val();
  if( $select == "user_cpf"){
  var $busca = $('#busca');
  $('#busca').mask('999.999.999-99');
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="select" style="width:100px;" title="Escolha..." name="select"> 
            <option>Escolha...</option>             
            <option value="user_nome">Nome</option>
            <option value="user_cpf">CPF</option>
            <option value="user_email">Email</option>
            <option value="user_loja">Loja</option>
        </select>

    <input type="text" id="busca" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite sua busca" name="busca" style="width:250px;">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cria um objeto para mapear as máscaras. E depois podes usar assim:

```js
var mascaras = {
  user_cpf: '999.999.999-99',
  // aqui podes ter mais campos
}

$('#select').on('change', function() {
  var mask = mascaras[this.value];
  if (mask) $('#busca').mask(mask);
  else $('#busca').unmask();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="select" style="width:100px;" title="Escolha..." name="select"> 
    <option>Escolha...</option>             
    <option value="user_nome">Nome</option>
    <option value="user_cpf">CPF</option>
    <option value="user_email">Email</option>
    <option value="user_loja">Loja</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="busca" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite sua busca" name="busca" style="width:250px;">
```